Availability group failover-tempdb
Does anyone know if SQL AG will initiate automatic failover to secondary if tempdb is full in primary ? I believe Database level health detection is only for user database in AG


Does anyone know if SQL AG will initiate automatic failover to secondary if tempdb is full in primary ?

It won't fail over, there's no problem with the databases and the instance is not failing health checks.
